# Unable to see deployed SOAP web service in wildfly 9.0

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wildfly-9

I am using wildfly 9  and Java 1.8 to deploy a simple SOAP webservice. Here is my code

public class Hello {

```
@WebMethod
public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello" + name;
}
```

}

When I deploy this in wildfly I cant see this under **subsytems>undertow** and when i try to access my wsdl using the url http://hostname:port/contextroot/Hello?wsdl as shown in my web.xml I get HTTP 404. My web.xml is empty with just  element.

Not sure whats missing and why wildfly doesnt recognise my webservice and why I get 404 error.

Comment: My class is annotated with @WebService annotation

Comment: The URL http://:/contextroot/Hello?wsdl is incorrect. Thus the 404 not found error. What is your project name?  Check your web.xml for more information

Comment: URL is http://<localhost>:<portnumber>/<contextroot>/Hello?wsdl. http://localhost:8080/myweb/Hello?wsdl